# Making server-side rendered content interactive on the client (SSR + Client-Side JS)

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, nestjs, server-side-rendering

I am currently experimenting with a few thoughts and concepts regarding the utilization of server side rendering (SSR). So far, I have set out to use NestJS, since it lets me use the MVC pattern that I am very used to from PHP. However, what I learned thus far is that the general usage is to send only a HTML shell to the client and feed this with additional data (PWA).

But what I would like to do is to render my content on the server, and add interactiveness to the client as it arrives there - and pick up from there and continue to render as if it was a PWA.

So far, what I found, was that frameworks like Vue and React - and others - have a method called `.hydrate()`, which works like their regular `.render()` method, only that it takes existing HTML and re-uses that to attach listeners and handlers to them, minimizing the need to render on the client. This does put more work on the server, but reduces the "time untill content" on the client quite some. Also, it retains a lot of SEO functionality for search engines that do not have JawaScript crawling capabilities like Google.

However, it seems that hydration can only be done - and please correct me when I am wrong - if the following conditions are met:

- The server- and client-side routing is identical. As in, the server and client must have the same components available and the same router in place.
- Hydration only works within one and the same framework (React can not render Vue). This is quite understandable, since it is a specific implementation.

So for this to work, I would have to "essentially" write my application targeting the server, like it was the client, then configure WebPack - or any other bundler - to build almost the same application for the client, minus the server handling (HTTP stuff).

But is this really true? Is it actually possible to dynamically construct a page, send it to the client, and let the client take over from there, even to the point where it can do any additional rendering?

To demonstrate what I want to do, consider the following flow of events:

- The client connects to the server, requesting `/foo`. (`HTTP/1.1 GET /foo`)
- The server processes the request and generates a partial, containing only what would need to go into `<body>`.
- The partial is inserted into a HTML shell, which includes a reference to a client-side script `client.js`.
- The client receives the output of the rendering process and runs `client.js`.
- The client uses the components within `client.js` to hydrate the contents of the HTML document sent by the server.
- The user now clicks on a link leading to `/bar`.
- The client issues a request to the server for `/bar`. But instead of being returned another full HTML document, only the partial - or just a JSON object - is being sent back.
- The client inserts the partial into the document, hydrates it once again, and restores interactiveness. The site now effectively behaves like a PWA, although it was initially server-rendered.

I would like to stick with NestJS because of it's MVC concept. But I would like to know if this idea of a mixed SSR/PWA experience is possible?

Thanks!